# Saving a Daggity model online

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs

Just wondring if any one has much experience with [www.dagitty.net](http://www.dagitty.net) for creating DAGS. I am having trouble saving the plot. I understand that you should be able to select the "model" button and export as pdf, but i only get the options for new model, latex code and load from daggity.net

Any one know what I am doing wrong?